# How to modify the text file by java language?

Tags: java, ms-word, document

I am having a database . For checking purpose , we are having a script for count the irrelevant entries.

If count is 0, the table or column is not having any problem.

If the count is 1, the table or column is having some irrelevant data. i need to delete the count (0) entries in the word file.

```sql
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CDSWEB.NBHISTORY WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND POLICYSTATUS IN (105,110,126,127,128,140,141,142,143,146,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161) AND STAGE  != 9;

  COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
         0                                                                      

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> 
SQL> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> ---General Rule for BGAs: The Primary Advisor on the first Policy encountered for a contact should be set as the Primary Advisor associated with the contact record unless the Primary Advisor already exists on the Contact record.'(ADDED ON 27TH AUGUST BY SHYAM)-- ---
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CONTACT WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND SUBSYSTEMTYPE IN(1,6)AND PRIMARYAGENT IS NULL AND CONTACTID IN(SELECT CONTACTID FROM INTERESTPARTY WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND PARTYROLE BETWEEN 1 AND 19 AND HOLDINGID IN(SELECT HOLDINGID FROM INTERESTPARTY WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND PARTYROLE BETWEEN 10001 AND 10003));

  COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
        69                                                                      

Elapsed: 00:02:28.29
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> ---INTERESTPARTY
SQL> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> 
SQL> ---- Here are Total Record Count of Policy does not have Primary Advisor,Insured,Payer,Owner.
SQL> ---- As per SmartOfice Logic, For all converted Policy Should have Primary Advisor,Insured,Payer,Owner.
SQL> --- However, conversion may bring blank Primary Contact. Check the source database for such blank records
SQL> --- and update the release notes to provide this information.
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CDSWEB.INTERESTPARTY WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND PARTYROLE IN (10001,6,1,2) AND CONTACTID IS NULL;

  COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
         0                                                                      

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL> 
SQL> --- To Verify The All Interestparty Record Are Linked With Policy.
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CDSWEB.INTERESTPARTY WHERE OFFICEID = 593 AND HOLDINGID IS NULL;

  COUNT(*)                                                                      
----------                                                                      
         0
```

I need to have an output like only counted records only, not count(0) records.

Comment: Query not clear

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to understand, but after reading it several times, I think you are trying to generate a report based upon multiple queries (shown in your question), but only want to see the results of the non-zero counts.

If my guess is incorrect, please refine your question with an actual example of what you are expecting to see.

Firstly, the good news (unless you really want to use java, ms-word and or a document), you can do all of this in SQL.

You need to use a union and a derived table. Here is a query that should give you what you need.

```sql
select qry_name, cnt
from (
  SELECT 'query 1 name' as qry_name, count(*) as cnt
  FROM CDSWEB.NBHISTORY
  WHERE OFFICEID = 593
    AND POLICYSTATUS IN (105,110,126,127,128,140,141,142,143,146,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161)
    AND STAGE  != 9
  group by qry_name

  union all

  SELECT 'query 2 name' as qry_name, count(*) as cnt
  FROM CONTACT
  WHERE OFFICEID = 593
    AND SUBSYSTEMTYPE IN(1,6)
    AND PRIMARYAGENT IS NULL
    AND CONTACTID IN (
      SELECT CONTACTID
      FROM INTERESTPARTY
      WHERE OFFICEID = 593
        AND PARTYROLE BETWEEN 1 AND 19
        AND HOLDINGID IN (
          SELECT HOLDINGID
          FROM INTERESTPARTY
          WHERE OFFICEID = 593
            AND PARTYROLE BETWEEN 10001 AND 10003
          )
      )
  group by qry_name

  union all

  SELECT 'query 3 name' as qry_name, count(*) as cnt
  FROM CDSWEB.INTERESTPARTY
  WHERE OFFICEID = 593
    AND PARTYROLE IN (10001,6,1,2)
    AND CONTACTID IS NULL
  group by qry_name

  union all

  SELECT 'query 4 name' as qry_name, count(*) as cnt
  FROM CDSWEB.INTERESTPARTY
  WHERE OFFICEID = 593
    AND HOLDINGID IS NULL
  group by qry_name
  ) as rep
where cnt > 0
;
```

How does it work?

Firstly, you include a string literal in your individual queries. The string literal identifies the query with the non-zero count in the final output.

Next, since you are selecting a "scalar" value, you must group by it. Many databases allow you to reference the column name, others allow you to group by column position (e.g. `group by 1`) others require that you repeat the expression (e.g. `'Query 1 name'`). **This must be done in each sub query**. You can use whatever text you like for the qry_name columns, just use something that uniquely identifies each query.

After that, simply union all of your queries together - this will produce four records - because you have four queries that return a single record each.

Finally, wrap the whole thing in a derived table and of the four records generated, just return the ones with a non-zero count. This is the derived table bit:

```sql
select qry_name, cnt
from (
   ... Rest of your four (or more) queries go here)
) as rep
where cnt > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but i have more than 350 queries in the script....If it is in java program...may be easy process but i dont know how to execute this in java?

Comment: I need this output in log file...we can get this ouput in oracle ..but we give to the client by tesxt file ..they need to delete the count (0) files ...i need non zero counts in that text file.

Comment: What have you done so far to try to achieve this? Have you tried searching on Google? There are literally thousands of examples of how to run queries against Oracle (and other dbms) and the same for how to write data to a file. Here is one example for querying Oracle. https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database